# Using MongoDB Update upsert

Tags: mongodb

There are like 5 update operators: $inc, $rename, $setOnInsert, $set, and $unset

When doing a update with upsert option set to true, what will be the value of a newly created document (considering that it does not exist, thus, upsert it), for a field with this update query:

```
{$inc: {age: 1}}
```

So the newly inserted document will have the value 1? since It does not exist before. Am I right?

If the operator is `$rename`, the what would be the value of the field, `null`? Or the field will not be created as part of the new document to be inserted?

**Update:**

If the update query is a rename update:

```
db.students.update( { _id: 1 }, { $rename: { 'nickname': 'alias', 'cell': 'mobile' } } )
```

Comment: 1. doc says: "If the field does not exist, $inc sets the field to the specified amount." so you are right / I dont get the rename thing, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: there is no upsert for rename queries? right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following steps in RockMongo, which should answer your question about $rename:

1. In a new db/collection, insert a document {"a": 1}
2. Update it with "$rename": {"b": "c"}
3. It says "1 rows may be affected."
4. Come back to the collection, there's still only one data: {"a": 1} (_id omitted). So yes, it just does nothing.

You may just try it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/rename/).

> When renaming a single field and the existing field name refers to a
>   non-existing field, the `$rename` operator does nothing.
>
> When renaming multiple fields and all of the old field names refer to
>   non-existing fields, the `$rename` operator does nothing.
>
> When renaming multiple fields and some but not all old field names
>   refer to non-existing fields, the `$rename` operator performs the
>   following operations:
>
> - Renames the fields that exist to the specified new field names.
> - Ignores the non-existing fields.